# dump 13 million rows to a file using oracle occi and c++

Tags: c++, oracle, optimization, fstream, occi

I am trying to export data from a table in database to a file in `csv` format.
I came up with below program .
My table contains about `13 million` rows and this program is very slow.

How can I speed up this program ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <occi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    oracle::occi::Environment* environment;
    oracle::occi::Connection *con;
    oracle::occi::Statement* stmt;
    oracle::occi::ResultSet* res;

    try
    {

        ofstream outfile;
        outfile.open("example.txt");
        string user ; cin>>user;
        string pass ; cin>>pass;
        string instance ; cin >>instance;
        environment = oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::DEFAULT);
        con = environment->createConnection(user,pass,instance);
        string query = "SELECT A,B FROM TABLE_X";

        stmt = con->createStatement(query);
        res = stmt->executeQuery();

        while (res->next())
        {
                outfile<<res->getInt(1)<<','<<res->getInt(2)<<'\n';
        }

        outfile.close();
        stmt->closeResultSet(res);
        con->terminateStatement(stmt);
        environment->terminateConnection(con);

    }catch(oracle::occi::SQLException &e){
        std::cout<<e.what();
    }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: tune size of receivig buffer, write into file in backround thread, use mmap to write into the file.

Answer (score 3):

Use array fetch to reduce database round tripping. The following is from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14294/performance.htm#CHDIDIDE). I would experiment with values 20,50,100,1000 to find optimal value for "NumROws" in the example below.

> Example 11-1 How to use Array Fetch with a ResultSet

```
ResultSet *resultSet = stmt->executeQuery(...);
resultSet->setDataBuffer(...);
while (resultSet->next(numRows) == DATA_AVAILABLE)
   process(resultSet->getNumArrayRows() );
```

> This causes up to numRows amount of data to be fetched for each
>   column. The buffers specified with the setDataBuffer() interface
>   should large enough to hold at least numRows of data.

Another strategy is to look split the task by ranges and have these running in parallel. If the export data must be in a single file then you can merge them separately (cat file1 file2 > file ).

What about the file system you are writing to? Is it slow? Have you tried writing to a different location? at the file system that the output is being written to.

Comment: +1 Very interesting !  Any idea what order of magnitude of performance improvement could be expected with this ?  Wasn't there supposed to be a client side object cache to reduce fetching time ?

Comment: @Christopher - I had one client who were using single row fetches (Java/JDBC) with a 2million row table and it was taking 60 seconds. Using the array fetches got it down time < 2 seconds (array size 100 I think was optimal for this cause). Obviously your actual results will vary, and there may be other bottlenecks, but single row fetches x 13million is going to hurt.

Comment: Set-based processing is the single biggest performance gain when working with data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you call slow.  But independently of the database fetchning, you could improve significantly the writing performance of file i/o by using `write()` instead of `operator<<`.

A little benchmark writing 1 million random csv pairs like yours showed following performance on my poor win8 pc :

```
operator<<  outputs at a rate of 7 Mb/s
write()     outputs at a rate of 40 Mb/s
```

That's more than 5 times faster, i.e. around 30 seconds for 13 millions entries.

The code in the looks uggly however, so upt to you to see if it's worth the effort:

```
    os << x << ',' << y << '\n';
```

becomes

```
    p=itoa(x, buff, 10); 
    while(*p)
        p++; 
    *p++ = ',';
    itoa(y, p, 10); 
    while(*p)
        p++;
    *p++ = '\n'; 
    *p++ = '\0';
    os.write(buff, p - buff);
```

where buff is a buffer allocated outside the loop.